# Can you help me for alert dialog like this picture in API 15 and API 19?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want use alert dialog like this picture for API 15 and API 19
[image: I want use alert dialog like this picture for API 15 and API 19]

Answer (score 0):

Use android `support v7 appcompat library` to achieve this.
The library is to maintain the backward compatibility. After adding this library to reference you can use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.

To find this library import the library project from `sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` and then use it in reference of your current project